# How a member func can know *programmatically* the 'name of the object' that is calling it?

Tags: c++, oop, programming-languages, object

Let say we have a class MyClass that has and a memberfunc(). 
An object is created for this MyClass, say ObjA.

```
i.e MyClass ObjA;
```

ObjA calls memberfunc().

Can we get this name 'ObjA' inside memberfunc() programatically?

Note: I know how to get the type of the object, i.e 'MyClass', using RTTI (Run-Time Type Identification), the same is also explained by radman below.

**EDIT:**

If this is NOT POSSIBLE in c++, Is it possible in any other programming language?

**EDIT2**

Made some modification to the question as few were unable to interpret.

Comment: http://www.aspectc.org/fileadmin/documentation/ac-quickref.pdf: static const char *signature()
gives a textual description of the join point (function name,
class name, ...)?

Comment: What do you want this name *for*? There might be workable solutions to the problem you're trying to solve in the first place.

Comment: @Anton: I do not want this for any production code. But while teaching some concepts to some one, if this is there, I hope it could help a lot. Anyways thanks for raising this point.

Comment: I think it's a bad idea for teaching, because it blurs the important distiction between compile-time (variable names) and runtime (memory locations). Consider adding a readonly string 'identity' field to your objects if you really wish to avoid memory addresses.

Comment: Of all the comments and answers, I believe Anton made the most important point: compile-time and runtime distinction is crucial, thus the problem is a bit ill-defined. The member func rather 'acts on' something (`this`) - after all, it might not have been invoked directly 'by an object' *at all* (callbacks, self-modifying code, etc.)

Comment: What if the object has no name? `(new MyClass)->memberfunc()` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several issues here:

1. Objects don't call anything, code does.
2. Objects don't have a name. An object is usually assigned to a variable, often to more than one variable, often to no variable at all, such as an array element.
3. Getting access to the call stack *might* give you some idea of the calling class that owns the code that called you, but even this usually requires a level of introspection that goes beyond the reflection facilities of most languages.

   - Python is a notable exception. It can give you the stack to walk and figure out lots of interesting things. C++ won't.

I have seen C++ libraries that crack open the stack (this is very non-portable, by the way) and thus give code the ability to figure stuff out like, "Who called me?" but I haven't used that stuff for years.

Comment: +1 But I would argue that array elements *are* variables, albeit anonymous ones.

Comment: In a sense, objects do have a name. It's their address. Not that that's the sort of name that the original questioner had in mind.

Comment: Java's log4j can tell you the Class and line # the log statement came from.  Other languages having logging frameworks that can do simiiar.  I believe log4j does it by throwing an exception, catching it and parsing the stack trace (or similar method).  ( With that in mind, I would guess that Python is not a 'notable exception' ). Also, Perl's Data::Dumper::Simple will tell you the name of the variable passed to its Dumper method.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way for it. C++ has no reflection, which <strike>would</strike> might make this possible. On 2nd thought, even the reflection facilities of e.g. Java don't have this feature.

C++ is compiled directly to machine code, which does not contain any identifiers from the source code anymore. You could of course store the "variable name" in a member field (provided the object is referred to under a single name...).

Comment: I don't think that reflection can actually help here either... reflection would provide information about the type of the object, but not the particular instance 'objA'.

Comment: Ok. I hope you are saying about RTTI (Real Time Type Identification) in c++!

Comment: @David, you are right, I just updated my post while you wrote this comment :-)

Comment: @AKN, I don't know much about it, sorry :-( But AFAIK even that would not help you here.

Answer (score 3):

No, the object name is something that only exists in your source code. Once compiled, the object reference is just a memory offset. If you want to know the variable name, you have to have a string somewhere describing it.

The facility to get a variable name in languages with introspection mechanisms (such as Reflection) is pretty limited and not at all widely available. Even in C# - the girly man language - to get a variable name you need to use a quirky C# 3.5 feature called projection and then jump through hoops to extract it. Even then, you have to program for it - it won't just be available at any point of the code.

After some thinking the question you are posing - getting the objects' name from a member function - is **theoretically impossible**. Consider this scenario:

```
class ObjA {
public:
  void memberfunc() {
    //confused??? instance1 or instance2?
  }
};

//main
ObjA instance1;
ObjA* instance2 = &instance1;
instance2->memberfunc();
```

In the above example we have one instance of `ObjA` with two variables pointing to it(and I use term **pointing** rather loosely here). Those variables are something completely outside of any conceivable control of the object, hence it's impossible to get at them, even if the facility to get a variable name is available.

In C# you can use anonymous classes and Reflection to get a variable name. The method of doing so is quite awkward and if you are trying to use this to demonstrate something to someone, give up now, because you will both be confused. The technique uses some features that are new to mainstream programming and include anonymous classes, projection, extension methods and Reflection.

```
public static class Extensions {
  public static string GetFirstPropertyName(this object obj) {
    return obj.GetType().GetProperties()[0].Name;
  }
}

public class Program {
  public static void Main() {
    int intVal = 5;
    var name = (new {intVal}).GetFirstPropertyName();
    //name=="intVal"
  }
}
```

Comment: Real men punch programs in machine code directly onto 7-hole tape.

Comment: Tape?  Only pussies use tape.  If you're not moving wires, you're not doing real programming!

Answer (score 0):

Well your question seems a little bit unclear but assuming that you want to print out the name of the class in one of it's member functions it is quite possible.

What you need to use is the [typeid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeid) command. This extracts a close to human readable name for a an object of class type at runtime. However you can't rely on this name being consistent across platforms i.e. the name you get may vary from platform to platform (what I got from the example code below was '4ObjA'.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
class ObjA
{
public:
  void memberfunc()
  {
    std::cout << typeid(*this).name() << std::endl;

  }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ObjA obj;
  obj.memberfunc();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear - do you want to know the object the method belongs to? Or the name of the method calling the member-function? Oo something else..?

In most object-oriented languages, you can get the name of the currently class quite easily:

```
class Myclass(object):
    def memberfunc(self):
        print self.__class__.__name__

obja = Myclass()
obja.memberfunc() # prints Myclass
```

You can't sensibly get the `obja` identifier as a name (in almost any language), and I can't see why you would want to (in cases like this, you'd use some kind of key/value mapping)

If you want to get the name of the method that called the method, you would have to inspect the call stack, e.g in Python using the `inspect` method:

```
import inspect

class Myclass(object):
    def memberfunc(self):
        current_call = inspect.stack()[0]
        previous = inspect.stack()[1]
        print previous[3]

def somefunc():
    obja = Myclass()
    obja.memberfunc() # prints somefunc

somefunc()
```

I imagine this isn't as easy in other languages

Again, the cases where you would want to do such a thing are rare, usually limited to introspection-heavy things like code coverage tools and debuggers

Comment: I was asking for 'the name of the method calling the member-function' and you have rightly answered it as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As has been covered in other posts, there is no direct way to access the variable name identifier that you choose in code at runtime - there is simply no need for it from the machine perspective. However, in Ruby it is trivial to get at the details of the caller in terms of its structure:

```
class Foo
   def foo
      puts self.class
   end
end

class Bar < Foo
end

f = Foo.new
b = Bar.new

f.foo #=> Foo
b.foo #=> Bar
```

You can do similar in C++ with `typeid`, but it is not exact. For instance:

```
#include <iostream>
class Foo {
    public:
        void foo () { std::cout << typeid(this).name() << std::endl; }
};

int main () {
    Foo f;
    f.foo ();  // on my system returns P3Foo
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a hack, but you could use Macros to store the class identifier name.  Here's what I mean:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define createMyClass(x) MyClass x("x")

class MyClass{
    string _name;
    MyClass( const string& name ) : _name(name){}
    memberfunc(){
        std::cout << "Name: " << _name << std::endl;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    createMyClass( ObjA );
    ObjA.memberfunc(); // prints the name
    return 0;
}
```